# change np to pandas to avoid memoryerror

Tags: python, math, plot, filter, signal-processing

I tried to fix this code many times, yet it still keep the same problem. Here the error code of Python Language that I received:

```
#Impulse response
# impulse signal
imp = np.zeros(20)
imp[0] = 1
```

I could not figure on why I keep getting ''MemoryError: Unable to allocate 449. TiB for an array with shape (7352320, 8388608) and data type float64'?
[enter image description here][https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK8GO.png]

Here's my full code(edited):https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hAvzTGNdR9TaqVPi0CCpM5usuftkBQWS68_dQ3VULNY/edit

I think there's no error in the code so far since I copied it from this link (https://www.gaussianwaves.com/2020/02/how-to-design-a-simple-fir-filter-to-reject-unwanted-frequencies/). Only the audio that I changed. The graph should be shown just like in the link......

Comment: Like the error message says, you don't have 449 terabytes of RAM. You need to simplify your problem so it can fit into your available memory.

Comment: can tell me how because im newbie to these codes...